# How to get string from a django.utils.safestring.SafeText

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm getting a django.utils.safestring.SafeText in my unit test:

```
ipdb> mail.outbox[0].body
u'Dear John Doe,<br>\n<p>\nYou have received a ..

ipdb> type(mail.outbox[0].body)
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>
```

I would like to convert the above into a string, so that I can strip out the `\n` characters.. ie I want to use the `rstrip()` method.. but I obviously can't do that on a `django.utils.safestring.SafeText` object. Ideas?

Comment: Pass it through `django.utils.encoding.force_text`?

Comment: force_text didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create new string based on SafeText

```
str(mail.outbox[0].body)
```

Answer (score 31):

As of Django 2.0.4, `str(mail.outbox[0].body)` no longer works -- it returns the same SafeText object. (See [this Django commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/ccfd1295f986cdf628d774937d0b38a14584721f) for why.)

Instead, you can add an empty string to get a regular string back:

`type(mail.outbox[0].body + "") == str`

In case it helps anyone else, I ran into this problem because I was trying to pass a SafeText from Django into `pathlib.Path`, which throws `TypeError: can't intern SafeText`. Adding an empty string fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the things you want to do with `django.utils.safestring.SafeText` object.You can apply almost every method as string on SafeText object. Available methods are

```
'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill'
```

But they will return unicode object. Example:-

```
>>> from django.utils.safestring import SafeText
>>> my_safe_text = SafeText('Dear John Doe,<br>\n<p>\nYou have received a ..  ')
>>> type(my_safe_text)
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>
>>> my_replaced_unicode = my_safe_text.replace('\n','')
>>> my_replaced_unicode
u'Dear John Doe,<br><p>You have received a ..  '
>>> type(my_replaced_unicode)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> my_rstriped_unicode = my_safe_text.rstrip()
>>> my_rstriped_unicode
u'Dear John Doe,<br>\n<p>\nYou have received a ..'
>>> type(my_rstriped_unicode)
<type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: this works on the python command line.. but it doesn't work in the actual code